# It's Impossible to set a Scrolling Javascript Ticker/Marquee to 100% Width

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So a client's website requires a scrolling javascript marquee. I know it sounds so 90s, but actually it's a pretty cool project that, in part, aims to replicate watching TV news. Unfortunately, every solution I've found so far cannot be set to width:100%;

The last script I've tried: http://www.mioplanet.com/rsc/newsticker_javascript.htm

Is there some core component of what I'm asking that makes it impossible to set the width:100%?

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong with using 100% width on the OUTER element of a scrolling area (the clipping region). However if you're trying to set the INNER div to 100% or less it won't be able to scroll.

In short you're doing something wrong because every scroller I have seen works at 100% width. I've never heard of the one you're using so maybe it's got a bug. Try an alternative one (there are tons).

Comment: I haven't seen a single javascript one that works at 100% width. All of them have some arbitrary default pixel width, and setting to 100% breaks them. [another that breaks is available here](http://remysharp.com/2008/09/10/the-silky-smooth-marquee/)

Comment: Then you simply haven't looked hard enough. You just need one where you can set the width of the 'slider' or 'inner' part independently of the 'outer' part. http://webdesignledger.com/tutorials/13-super-useful-jquery-content-slider-scripts-and-tutorials

Comment: or that 100% is 100% of an element that has margins or padding you forgot about?
I know for a fact it can be done. for the record, are you trying to get 100% screen width, or 100% of an element's width?